# Remote desktop to Ubuntu

Tags: vps, ubuntu

I have a VPS server running Ubuntu OS and also have shell access to my server. I wonder is there any way to connect to Ubuntu desktop and see its UI from windows using remote desktop tools such as TeamViewer or what ever apps?

Is that possible or I have to deal with my server using just command line?

Answer (score 7):

I'm 100% positive (OK - 99.999999%) that there is no GUI running on your Ubuntu VPS -- no point to waste resources for something that never will be used -- everything can be managed via command line.

If you want to use tools like TeamViewer/VNC server, you will have to install GUI first (KDE/Gnome/etc) which will eat extra RAM/CPU which you, most likely, have limited amount. Even if it can work without GUI -- you still will end up with console only -- pure SSH connection will be faster anyway.

So yeah -- console is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you need to do but like LazyOne said, you shouldn't use a gui on a server since it is going to use a lot of the resources.

However, if you need it is possible. You will need to install the gui packages and to allow X11 forwarding. You then need to connect with ssh with a client that support X11, If you are on windows you can use [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)

However, if the reason you want to use a gui is because you don't feel confident with the command line, it will be really hard for you to make it work.